# Algorithm needed: Draw Outline Round Dots

Tags: vector-graphics, image-recognition

Is there a well established algorithm I can steal^h^h^h^h^h copy which will draw an outline shape given an area filled with dots ?

I'm specifically thinking of this:

John Conway's Life: it might be nice way to see Life from the 'design-stance' (Dan Dennet's phrase) - and one way of doing this would be to draw outlines around either known patterns : or perhaps joining-the-dots : drawing the line on the furthest - but still interacting dots in a particular area.

So a glider would still look like a glider pretty much: but bigger shapes would just show their outline.

I haven't thought this through probably [as some patterns involve 'separated', non-interacting dots - only destined to interact in a future generation - I guess you could factor in a temporal interaction like this?] , and should have posted to 'www.halfbakery.com' , but maybe this is interesting .....

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) ([convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms)).